# 403 Forbidden: Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity) while using Youtube Playlist list API

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch playlist by channel, When I try to test it I am getting 403 access denied, but I have enabled api youtube api v3 while generating API Key. I have attached the error log below.

**Note:** I have passed my key using constructor and initialized it and used that variable as youtube in my code.

**private YouTube youtube;**

**Code to fetch list of playlist by channel:**

```
public List<Playlist> fetchChannelPlaylists(String channelId) throws Exception {
        List<String> playlistParts = new ArrayList<String>();
        playlistParts.add("snippet");
        playlistParts.add("contentDetails");

        YouTube.Playlists.List playlistsListByChannelIdRequest = youtube.playlists()
            .list(playlistParts)
            .setChannelId(channelId);

        PlaylistListResponse response = playlistsListByChannelIdRequest.execute();
        return response.getItems();
    }
```

**Error:**

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?channelId=Ut-zmw&part=snippet
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
      "reason": "forbidden"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: Where have you done any authentication here?

Comment: With what actual `channelId` have you tried with? It seems you censored it: `channelId=Ut-zmw`.